# What does the grave accent symbol (`) ( not single quote) represent in PHP?

Tags: php

In the example below, what do the grave accents in the second line mean?

```
$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss $second -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $image 2>&1";

$return = `$cmd`
```

Comment: That's not an acute accent, that's a grave accent. The acute accent faces the other way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It executes a shell command. So it executes whatever is in $cmd.

See [backtick operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php)

Answer (score 8):

It is a [shorthand](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) for [`exec()`](http://php.net/exec). The output of the command can be directly used in an expression.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

(Please note that you still should apply [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) to variables in the command string beforehand.)