# What are the rules of string manipulation when using backticks (grave accents)?

Tags: php, string, shell, backticks

In PHP when you write a set a variable equal to a string wrapped in grave accents, it gets executed as it would if it were inside a `shell_exec()` command. [What does the grave accent symbol (`) ( not single quote) represent in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6071562/680578)

So, in php you can do all sorts of things to combine strings with variables, etc, what can I and can't I do when using ` instead of ' or " ?

Comment: You may have more luck with the term "backtick."  The character only becomes an accent once it's combined with a letter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the PHP, that character is called a backtick operator.

A literal string wrapped in backticks is a `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE` token. You can confirm this by running something like this:

```
print_r(token_get_all('<?php `uname`;'));
```

which gives you this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 367
            [1] => <?php 
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => `
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 313
            [1] => uname
            [2] => 1
        )

    [3] => `
    [4] => ;
)
```

And then run `token_name(313)` which gives you `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`.

To the parser, a string wrapped in backticks is equivalent to a [string with variables in it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) like `"hello $world"`. The literal/constant part of the string (the `hello` part) is `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`.

So to answer your question, anything that you can do to a string that contains variables you can do to a string wrapped in backticks.

So why `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`? Probably, because like a string containing variables, it's value is determined at runtime. Whereas a `T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` (a normal literal string) is kind of like a constant in the eyes of the parser.